# JSON serialize is not handling aggregate results properly in Spring 13

Tags: apex, json, api-27

> string testSerialize = JSON.serialize(database.query('SELECT COUNT(Id)
>   custTot, Industry Indus from Account Group by Industry'));
>
> system.debug('test '+ testSerialize);

Ran this query in developer console Spring 13 both sandbox and production results in producing the below output

> [{"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"}},{"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"}},{"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"}},{"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"}},{"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"}}]

Before Spring 13 it returns data after this upgrade causing problems.

Comment: I got the same issue in the Spring'13 preview, for the Winter'13 org, it is fine.

Comment: One of my org is upgraded to Winter 13 In all pages it is breaking. So wired to see this issue in salesforce and raised support ticket replied they was doing R&D and there was no time line commit to fix this.

Comment: Uggggh, that's nasty. Hope they get that resolved soon. I've got JSON serialization sprinkled all over the place.

Comment: @UgeshGali What is the case number that you raised?

Comment: @grigriforce Sorry about late reply Partner Portal Case Number: #08618428

Comment: @UgeshGali We have premiere support so I've logged a case as well. Hopefully that will get it a bit more attention.

Comment: @grigriforce Did you get any response from them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that this was fixed in the latest patch release. Here are the (correct) results that I'm getting in a spring 13 sandbox.

```
string testSerialize = JSON.serialize(database.query('SELECT COUNT(Id) custTot, Industry Indus from Account Group by Industry'));
system.debug('test '+ testSerialize);

01:21:37:134 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|test [{"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"},"custTot":32,"Indus":null}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After escalating to so many levels they released a patch.